# Recover Notes data after factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery

I have an OnePlus One phone that was then on an old version of Cyanogenmod I factory reset by accident a few years ago. I used the OS notes app back then (it wasn't backed up) and I would like to recover them.

When looking at the files on the phone from USB on my Macbook pro a while back, I noticed there was a folder called O which has seemingly a whole new OS file tree.

I used the phone after the factory reset and after a while when I ran out of disk space quickly (it has 64gb) and on using the space calculator in settings I found out 22gb was being used Misc! I am assuming this is the old OS and so wonder if the notes can be recovered. Looking through the files on my Macbook file explorer on the phone I have not been able to find the notes data files. I Googled a while back and I think the notes are stored in XML.

Is it possible to recover these?

Answer (score -1):

Coolmuster Lab.Fone for Android can help you recover notes data after factory reset from Oneplus phone. You just need to make sure the notes data not being overwritten by new data.